# Exposed SQL Datetime query condition

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have a table that has two fields of type Datetime and int.

```
object DummyTable : IntIdTable("db.table", columnName = "id") {
    val createdAt = datetime("created_at")
    val mins = integer("mins")
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
}
```

I have a function where i want to check the condition that createdAt plus mins is less than the Datetime now.

```
 fun isValid(id: String): String? {
      return DummyTable.select{
          COND??
        }.single()[DummyTable.age]
    }
```

Something like this:

```
DummyTable.createdAt plus minutes   lessEq  DateTime.now()??
```

What would be the query condition?

Answer (score 3):

I thought that the answer on [github](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1021#issuecomment-681821446) was enough.

```kotlin
class DateAddMins(val dateExp: Expression<DateTime>, val addMins: Expression<Int?>) : Expression<DateTime>() {
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = queryBuilder {
        append("DATE_ADD(", dateExp, ", INTERVAL IFNULL(", addMins, ", 0) MINUTE)")
    }
}

DummyTable.select { 
    DateAddMins(DummyTable.createdAt, DummyTable.mins) lessEq DateTime.now) 
}
```